# Good idea to use mobile device UUID for login?

Tags: iphone, mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use phonegap and jQuery mobile to develop an app and I work with these two technologies for the first time.

Now the user should login to the remote server. I have a JSON service ready for it, session will be stored at the remote server. To make everything comfortable, I would like the user to login only one time. Here is my process:

1) phone looks at the remote directory - is my UUID allowed at a specific account?

1a) if yes, login

1b) if no, proceed with 2

2) Login

2a) If login succeeded, store UUID at the users account. Delete UUID from other accounts, if it has been stored there

2b) If login failed, go to 2

Now my question: for security reasons, is it a good idea to use UUID as "key"? Or can it be manipulated in a nasty way?

The other option is to store the password (hashed) on the iphone.

What is best practice?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about the device identifier, which Apple calls the "UDID".

Using the UDID for that purpose doesn't seem like a good idea to me. From your purposes, there's no difference between a UDID and any other 40-digit hex string. From the user's perspective, though, it's an unchangeable string that's not private and which is being used as a stand-in for their username and password. Since any application can discover the UDID, and the UDID is given freely to developers and others, the security of your entire system will rest on nothing more than the obscurity of your hashing algorithm.

It *might* be okay to use the UDID as a stand-in for the user name *if* you require the user to enter a password at the beginning of each session because then there'd at least be a private, changeable component of the login combination.

I don't see any real advantage in using the UDID compared to a random 40-digit hex string that you generate in your app. The advantages of generating your own string, on the other hand, are that no other app can easily discover your string and the user can (if you let them) change the string at will.

Note: I'm not a security expert, and I don't mean to give the impression that I am. However, as a user, I'd be nervous about using an app that uses the device id the way you describe.

Comment: You are right, any other app on the same device could easily log in. But if I would use a has from password/username this would not be very easily reckognized. I might be able to store this hash on the phone, as it is not a clean password. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID as key. You can also convert UUID(Hashed) though UUID is unique for every device. As per my concern you should use UUID concept. It is much better than password(hashed) stored on the phone.

Comment: As Caleb pointed out below, every app on the device could then easily log in.

Comment: @Christian thanks for the information. I am doing some silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

As long as the UUID isn't being used as the sole unique identifier for a user it should be fine. Just remember that the UUID identifies the device, not the user. The user could lose or break their phone and have to get a new one, which wold mean the UUID changes. It'll still be the same user, using a different phone.